# Bean-To-XML annotations: how to process nested structure

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cxf, aegis

For bean->xml convertion in webservices we use Aegis from CXF (it is jaxb-compatible, as I understand).

This is my type:

```
class C{
private int a;
private int b;
private T t;
...
}

class T{
private int t1;
private int t2;
}
```

I need `t.t1` field to be on the same level in XML as `a` and `b` in `C` (bean restored from xml should be like this:

```
class C{ 
private int a; 
private int b;
private int t1 
}
```

(client code is interested only in field `t1` from structure `T`).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `getT1()` and `setT1(int)` to `C` and make `getT()` `@XmlTransient`

```
class C {
  // snip

  /**
   * JAXB only
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  @XmlElement
  private void setT1(int t1) {
    if(t != null) {
      t.setT1(t1);
    } else {
      // TODO
    }
  }

  /**
   * JAXB only
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private int getT1() {
    if(t != null) {
      return t.getT1(t1);
    } else {
      // TODO
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution probably works, but I don't want to add additional public methods to my class. It can confuse other developers, if they see two ways of reading/setting one variable 
c.getT().setT1(1), and c.setT1(). Of course, I can mark c.setT1() as deprecated or add comments, but if it is possible, I would like to avoid such code.

Comment: @dbf you could also make these methods private. This requires explicitly annotating them with `@XmlElement` though.

Comment: @dbf another possibility would be to use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` and replace `C` with another object (could be a class that extends or wraps `C`) that contains the properties you want.

Comment: sfussenegger XmlJavaTypeAdapter is good, but I have a problem: it is not called during webservice method invocation. Does Aegis mapping support @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation?

Comment: sorry, can't help you with aegis

Comment: No, aegis doesn't support the type adapters.   That's jaxb only.   That would then bring up the question of why don't you just use jaxb?

Comment: Daniel, we don't use jaxb because with jaxb we get
minOccurs="0" for all variables in classes. In aegis we can change it with 
                <property name="defaultNillable" value="false"/>
                <property name="defaultMinOccurs" value="1"/>
and we can't find these options for jaxb.

Comment: @dbf isn't that what `@XmlElement(required = true)` is doing (on a per-property basis)? `@XmlElement(nillable = false)` is the default anyway.

Comment: Yes, I want to set @XmlElement(required = true), but once in config file for all elements, not setting this annotation for EACh variable in EACH class.